# scala + play framework 2.5 - debugging don't working

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have problem with debugger in play framework 2.5 and scala. I use Intelij IDEA 2016.1 IDE, and when i try debug my applicaton, it never stops on  break points. I try 2 options:

1. Run application directly from Intelij IDEA as Play2App i debug mode.
2. Run application from activator by `activator -jvm-debug 9999` command, and connect from IDE as remote debug. Connection is succeed.
   In both approach, application don't stop on break points.

If i debug standalone apliaction (with main function), or unit test, all work correctly.

Do you have any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Eclipse and had the same issue with play 2.5.4.

Issue fixed after I removed "fork in run := true" from build.sbt

Hope it helps.